# Mapinfo Line and polygons from different layers to be snaped

Tags: layers, line, mapinfo, snapping

I have a layer that I need to edit [ kerb and gutter (KNG)] which consists only of lines that represent the kerb and gutters on both sides of the road. I have separated the left and right side of the KNG and label them accordingly.

The KNG naturally should be sitting inside roads. We have a layer called road section that contains polygons that traces the road.

I want to make each line of the KNG layer to be completely within their respective road sections (think the lines are continuous and connected but is snapped at the end of each road section) so that when I run a SQL with completely within, it should all show up.

There seems to be an issue with the bounds.

When I save the two tables without bounds and then pack the table, (I realised that packing the table after saving without bounds changes the bounds slightly) I am able to achieve what I want albeit needing to do a little bit of manual editing.

This, however, would not really work as I want to be able to get the KNG table into the corporate layer so that everyone can use it.

When I change the bound of the KNG so that it matches the bound of the road section layer, no matter what I do, the nodes on the KNG and road section would not snap.

**In the** **without bounds version**, I did:

Overlay node onto road section, then overlay nodes onto KNG lines. This somehow combines the two nodes. I can then run some SQL or do some manual edit to get the result I want.

The unbounded tables seem to just be allocated to a default bound, which is unnecessarily big for us.

**In the bounded version:**
Did the same as above, I can see that the two nodes are off by a few mm not a bit deal for us in the grand scheme of things but some SQL would not work.

Is there any function in **MapInfo** to allow me to make the end of a line snap with a node on a different layer within a threshold say 50cm or so?

Answer (score 1):

The MapCad -> Edit -> Snap/Thin tool looks like it will do what you want. It has a few options for repairing line, polyline and polygon geometries. The Inter-Object Node Snap will allow you to set the tolerances you require.